# How to disable restarting (ever) on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, crash, reboot

For some reason, my Laptop shutdowns fine, boots fine, BUT goes into a crash loop when restarted. I have spent so much time trying to fix this but nothing seems to work. So maybe I can ignore this issue by making sure that the computer never attempts to restart again. Even if I never restart it absent mindedly, some program can decide to restart without asking me, so I am wondering if it is possible to take some precautions.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Windows Updates cannot be disabled completely on Windows 10, which means, eventually it will install them automatically and restart your compute to finish the update.  What is possible is to solve your restart problem though.

Comment: which crash loop? Do you see a BSOD (sad face)?

Comment: @Ramhound do you know what might be the primary difference between restarting and shutdown+boot? I have spend over 100 hour trying to get this laptop to work to no avail.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes I get a sad face. I get a kernel security check failure most of the time.

Comment: @Ramhound I have also discovered that the only way my laptop boots reliably is if fast boot is enabled (should I make post another question?)

Comment: ok, copy the folder **C:\windows\minidump** to your desktop, compress it as 7z/zip/RAR, upload the compressed file to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll look at it with a debugger

Comment: How to see bsod details instead of sad face...http://winaero.com/blog/show-bsod-details-instead-of-the-sad-smiley-in-windows-10/

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3O9lupcWG-wSDJmcERELUxmZUU/view?usp=sharing thanks

Comment: the kernel security check failures are caused while NTFS operations. So check the SMART values of your HDD (http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) and if they are fine, run **chkdsk /f** to detect NTFS issues.

Comment: have you checked the HDD for issues?